# Nuxt.js рендер нужной страницы

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Есть приложение на nuxt.js и админка со страницами, на какой указиваються такие поля: slug, template (путь к шаблону) и сео метатеги.
Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на /page/_slug рендерился нужный контент?

Например:
`<nuxt path="/page/contacts/index"/>`.

Какие есть спрособы подключения, чтобы на странице /page/_slug подключалась страница, которая указана в админке в поле template ?
И как можно передать в `<nuxt-child>` страницу, которая не являеться дочерней?

Спасибо за ваши ответы. Буду благодарен любой подсказке!

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавь generate в nuxt.confing.js

```
  generate: {
    routes: ['my_route','404']
  },
```

Ну и дока: https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/basic-routes